# How to connect a row change in tableWIdget with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5

Working with python, I have a QTableWidget.

I need to perform computations with contents of the table
In my table constructor :

```
for i in range(rowNumber):
            for j in range(columnNumber):
                cellLineEdit = QLineEdit()
                cellLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.sync_lineEdit)
                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, j, cellLineEdit)
```

The sync_lineEdit function :

```
def sync_lineEdit(self, text):
    #perform computations using the table contents.
```

Is there a way to add the row of the table to the sync_lineEdit call? Ideally, I would love it to be a parameter of the sync_lineEdit function.

Comment: That depends: is the table layout fixed, or is it possible that rows are removed/inserted/moved or even sorted? Also, it seems you're trying to set a QLineEdit for *all* items. Are you sure about that approach? If your purpose is only to make all items in editing state, then that's not the proper way to do so. If you're doing it to avoid doubleclicking for starting editing of an item, again, the wrong way.

Comment: Table layout is fixed. I am not sure about the approach at all, beginner in python and PyQT; basically I have like 4 fields in my table needed for my computation. What would be the best way to make all items in editing state?

Comment: If those cells should ***always*** be in editing state, then you can use [`openPersistentEditor(item)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#openPersistentEditor). But that behavior might not be what you want, so it's important to understand how you're treating the data and *when* you want to react to user changes.

Comment: Does the persistentEditor gives me a way to solve my issue, which is getting my rows on the callbacks?

Comment: As said, it depends on *when* you want to react to user editing. While typing? When the user submits (possibly by pressing Enter/Return)? When the current cell is changed?

Comment: I want to react when the user press 'enter', finishing writing in a cell.

Comment: Then use `openPersistentEditor` as explained, and instead connect to the [`cellChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged) or [`itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signals of the table (note: don't do that in the `for` loops!!!)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @musicamante proposed, the following solution worked

In constructor :

```
rowNumber = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
columnNumber = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
    for i in range(rowNumber):
        for j in range(columnNumber):
            self.tableWidget.openPersistentEditor(self.tableWidget.itemAt(rowNumber, columnNumber))
    self.tableWidgetHomme.cellChanged.connect(self.sync_lineEdit)
```

The callback :

```
def sync_lineEditHomme(self, row, column):
    print("row = ", row, "column = ", column)
    #access an other element of the table for calculations :
    Value = int(self.tableWidget.item(row,0).text())
```